# Proof of normal topological space

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

$X$ is normal if for every two open sets $G_1,G_2\subseteq X$ with $G_1\cup G_2=X$, there exists closed sets $F_1\subseteq G_1$ and $F_2\subseteq G_2$ which also satisfies $F_1\cup F_2=X$.

Where can I find the proof for this theorem? I have found multiple proofs for other theorems about normal spaces, but not this one.

Comment: "=>" Let G1 and G2 be two open sets in a normal space X with X=G1∪G2. Then X \ G1, X \ G2 are disjoint closed sets. Since X is normal, then there exist disjoint open sets G′1 and G′2 such that X \ G1⊂G′1 and X \ G2⊂G′2. Let F1 = X \ G′1, F2 = X \ G′2. Then F1 and F2 are closed sets with F1⊂G1, F2⊂G2 and F1∪F2=X. Any tips for the reverse (if "=>" is correct)?

Comment: It's correct and the reverse is the same: Let $G_1, G_2$ be two sets then $G_1$ and $G_2$ are open with $G_1 \cup G_2 = X$ if and only if the complements are closed and disjoint. Etc...

Comment: BTW. Have you seen the theorems for necessary & sufficient conditions that a  $T_1$ space is hereditarily normal (a.k.a. completely normal) or hereditarily collection-wise normal ?

Comment: Actually, I have read that a space $X$ is called $T_4$, only if is normal and $T_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H_1,H_2$ be a disjoint pair of closed subsets of $X$. We seek a disjoint open pair $J_1,J_2$ with $H_1\subseteq J_1$ and  $H_2\subseteq J_2.$

Let $G_1=X\setminus H_1$ and $G_2=X\setminus H_2.$

Then $G_1,G_2$ are open. And $G_1\cup G_2=X.$ Because (by contradiction) $$(p\in X\land p\not\in G_1\cup G_2)\implies$$ $$ (\,(p\in X\land p\not \in G_1)\land (p\in X\land p\not\in G_2)\,)\implies$$ $$ (\,(p\in H_1)\land (p\in H_2)\,)\implies$$ $$ p\in H_1\cap H_2$$ but by hypothesis we have $H_1\cap H_2=\emptyset.$

Now, by the hypothesis of the Q, take closed  $F_1,F_2$  with $F_1\subseteq G_1$ and $F_2\subseteq G_2$ and $F_1\cup F_2=X.$

Let $J_1=X\setminus F_1$ and $=X\setminus F_2.$
Then $J_1, J_2$ are open . And $$J_1\cap J_2=(X\setminus F_1)\cap (X\setminus F_2)=$$ $$=X\setminus (F_1\cup F_2)=$$ $$=X\setminus (X)=\emptyset.$$

Finally we have  $$H_1\cap J_1=H_1\cap (X\setminus F_1)=$$ $$=H_1\setminus  F_1\supseteq H_1 \setminus G_1 \,\text {(...because } F_1\subseteq G_1...)$$ $$ = H_1 \setminus (X \setminus H_1)=H_1.$$ So $H_1\subseteq J_1.$Changing the subscript from $1$ to $2$ we also have $H_2\subseteq J_2.$